# c# publishing a project

Tags: c#, excel, exe

I have created a program which gets access to a database and then output the information into an **Excel File**. In my **bin/debug** folder I do use an **Excel template** and an **Excel workbook** where all the data gets input too.

In a later version I also wanted to save user input to an Excel file in the same directory and access it via my program.

Is there any way that i can give another user ( for test purposes ) my folder 
with maybe the .exe inside so that he can start and use the program ( and also the excel files located in bin/debug ) ?

Comment: By emailing the user??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, excel files located in bin/debug.

**and steps for publishing c# project are below:**

1. Add a setup project by clicking on File-> Add-> New Project.
2. Select here Setup and Deployment in the left side bar in project types.

   Here we find three options as following:

   - Application Folder
   - User's Desktop
   - User's Program Menu
3. These three options are the three places where we want to copy our setup fules during the installation process. From here we have to select one option. Suppose I select User's Desktop. Then Right click on User's Desktop option and select Add-> Project Output.
4. After clicking on Project Output, a new window will open. Here we select first four options. Now click on OK.
5. After clicking on OK, Rebuild the Setup from Build option in Menu bar.
6. After this, let's test our setup by going right clicking on the setup project in Solution Explorer and click on Install menu item.

   - The setup process will start
7. After completing the installation go on desktop there you will find all files you have included in the setup on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

First, let us know whether it is an **Windows application** or a **Web**?

Assuming it is a **Windows Application** :
Yes, you can provide the user the directory with the generated **exe** or any Shared Folders. You just need to **Build/Rebuild** the program in Release mode, later you can copy the files from the **Bin/Obj** folder to fetch the exe s and provide to the user.

Does that answer your Query or Is there anything else?

Comment: Id like to have an folder "MyProgramm" when u click on it there is a
MyProgramm.exe and a subfolder with the other stuff. And then zip the MyProgramm folder. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can copy the exe and the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click "Debug" directory, Send To -> Compressed (zipped) Folder
2. Right click Debug.zip, Send To -> Mail Recipient
3. Email to the other user
4. That's it!